# AWS Glue TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DynamicFrame' and 'str'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm building an ETL pipeline using AWS-Glue and I'm running into this error when running a job :

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DynamicFrame' and 'str'"

The job is processing data and then writing it out to a PostgreSQL database.

The job seems to be working fine in the sense that the processing is working and the PSQL database is being updated, but the job still reports this error every time it runs.

I'm a bit stumped because I'm basically using a modified version of the stock AWS job script.

Here is my code :

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

import pyspark.sql.functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Create a DynamicFrame using the Service ROs table
ros_DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="DB",        
table_name="TB", transformation_ctx = "ros_DyF")

# Do a bunch of processing...code not included...

# Update the tables in postgreSQL
psql_conn_options = {'database' : 'DB', 'dbtable' : 'TB'}
psql_tmp_dir = "TMPDIR"
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
frame = mapped_dyF,
catalog_connection = 'wizelyPSQL',
connection_options = psql_conn_options,
redshift_tmp_dir = psql_tmp_dir,
transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

job.commit()
```

Here's the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-07-09-19-30-30.py", line 168, in <module>
transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1531164400757_0001/container_1531164400757_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 597, in from_jdbc_conf
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1531164400757_0001/container_1531164400757_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 262, in write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1531164400757_0001/container_1531164400757_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 278, in     write_from_jdbc_conf
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1531164400757_0001/container_1531164400757_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 32, in write
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1531164400757_0001/container_1531164400757_0001_01_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 28, in     writeFrame
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DynamicFrame' and 'str'
End of LogType:stdout
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk just updated original post with code.  ty!

Comment: Code looks ok. Which line produce it? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk It's the glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf command that is producing the error.  The write seems to be working fine (it's writing the data to the PSQL db) - but I'd like to make the error go away so I don't have a job that is just producing errors every time it runs.  I updated the original post with the error log.

Comment: I was able to get this job to execute successfully by using the DataFrameWriter class from pyspark.sql.  

I tried every variant of the options referenced here, with the same error : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-write_dynamic_frame_from_options

Seems to be me there is a bug in the AWSGlue code - communicating with AWS about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a bug in PyGlue lib. However I checked source code and didn't didn any suspicious. Here is a line:

```
28.     return DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf, callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame.name + "_errors")
```

The error you are receiving would be produced if the line would be like this (removed `.name` from last parameter):

```
28.     return DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf, callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame + "_errors")
```

In this case your job would work since evaluation of the `self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(...)` happens before the string concatenation that produces error.

If you are using PySpark lib in [dev endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-repl.html) then try to download the latest version from `aws-glue-jes-prod-us-east-1-assets/etl/python/PyGlue.zip`. Otherwise, if you are composing script in Glue Console UI (lib is provided by AWS Glue service) then you should contact AWS support.

Comment: Thanks for the lead!  I am using the Glue Console UI and I've been going back and forth with AWS Support on this, but this is a good lead I will send to them.  Thanks again.